# sourceupdated event not firing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have DiscoveredHosts which is an `ObservableCollection<string>`.  The sourceupdated event is not being called.  Anyone know why?

```
<ComboBox Name="DiscoveredHostsComboBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="100px" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=
    DiscoveredHosts}" SourceUpdated="DiscoveredHostsComboBox_SourceUpdated" />

public void GetDomainHosts()
{
    DiscoveredHosts.Clear();

    var adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

    if (Config.Debug)
    {
        DiscoveredHosts.Add("192.168.73.11");
        DiscoveredHosts.Add("192.168.73.14");
    }

    foreach (var properties in adapters.Select(adapter => adapter.GetIPProperties()))
    {
        if (properties.DnsSuffix != "" && !DiscoveredHosts.Contains(
properties.DnsSuffix))
            DiscoveredHosts.Add(properties.DnsSuffix);

        if (properties.DnsAddresses.Count <= 0) continue;

        foreach (var host in properties.DnsAddresses.Where(host => !DiscoveredHosts.
Any(a => a == host.ToString())))
            DiscoveredHosts.Add(host.ToString());
    }

    OnPropertyChanged("DiscoveredHosts");
}
```

Comment: I don't get this: OnPropertyChanged("DiscoveredHosts");
Can you add the declaration of the DiscoveredHosts Property? I think the idea of using ObservableCollection is to avoid calling the OnPropertyChange Method "manually". Something does not look correct IMO.

Comment: Oh, yes.  I know that's the reason you use an ObservableCollection; however, someone challenged me that that might not be occurring and I had already considered the same issue.  I left that line in here so no one would say, "Why don't you try ..."  ha ha.  
        public ObservableCollection<string> DiscoveredHosts { get { return _discoveredHosts ?? (_discoveredHosts = new ObservableCollection<string>()); } }

Answer (score 3):

Please, set NotifyOnSourceUpdated to true for SourceUpdated event to fire:

```
<ComboBox Name="DiscoveredHostsComboBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="100px"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DiscoveredHosts, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
    SourceUpdated="DiscoveredHostsComboBox_SourceUpdated" />
```

Comment: NotifyOnSourceUpdated is a binding option, so set it up in the binding, not in the control.

Comment: Vincent, yeah, exactly, NotifyOnSourceUpdated should be within Binding element. Thanks for correction.