# Binding.SourceUpdated not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have a binding that works. The GUI updates.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Value, 
                              NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, 
                              NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, 
                              Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

The binding source object implements INotifyPropertyChanged and the binding property is a normal clr property.

The `Binding.TargetUpdated` event fires, but not the `Binding.SourceUpdated` event.

For example, the following works

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated"> ...
```

but

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.SourceUpdated"> ...
```

does not.

It makes no difference if I create the binding in code or XAML, use `EventTrigger` in the `Triggers` collection or an `EventSetter`. As far as I can tell the event is just not firing.

Does anyone know how to make `Binding.SourceUpdated` fire?

Comment: The reason is I would like to be able to access the Source object when the binding changes. Even better, I would like to easily get the source property (that is `obj.Value` in the above example). I can do this using reflection and the binding object from the target, but htat is very painful.

Comment: You have to change Mode=TwoWay...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could it be that 'TargetUpdated' is fired when the source changes and 'SourceUpdated' is fired when the target changes?

(@black-stallion gave me a hint to what might be going on, but I'm hoping people will comment / edit if this is correct or incorrect!)

Comment: [Binding.SourceUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.sourceupdated.aspx) Attached Event Occurs when a value is transferred from the binding target to the binding source.

Comment: I get it. So confusing the name is!

Comment: for me, this was the solution: 
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" SourceUpdated="VendorProperty_SourceUpdated"/>
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5619557/9258504